# errno 11 after initialize SDL

Tags: c, sdl-2, game-development, errno, sdl-image

After initialize SDL with SDL_Init and IMG_Init i observe the code 11 on errno. It means that Resource temporarily unavailable. But i don't know why. Please help me resolve this problem. I observe the value of errno before and after initialisation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../includes/init.h"
#include "../includes/map.h"
#include "../includes/startGame.h"
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
int game = 1;
SDL_Window* screen = NULL;
SDL_Renderer *screen_render = NULL;
SDL_Event e;

initAllScreenAndRenderer(&screen, &screen_render);

while (game){

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
        switch (e.type){
        case SDL_QUIT:
            game=0;
            break;

        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (e.key.keysym.sym){
                case  SDLK_a:
                play(&screen_render);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    SDL_RenderClear(screen_render);
    SDL_RenderPresent(screen_render);
}
destroyAllScreenAndRenderer(&screen, &screen_render);
}

void initAllScreenAndRenderer(SDL_Window **window, SDL_Renderer **window_renderer){
printf("\n%d\n", errno);

if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1 || IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG) != IMG_INIT_PNG){
    printf("\nError of initialisation : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(-1);
}
printf("\n%d\n", errno);

*window = SDL_CreateWindow(GAME_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, `SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);`
if (*window==NULL){
    printf("\nError of initialisation window : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(-1);
}
printf("\n%d\n", errno);

*window_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(*window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
if (*window_renderer==NULL){
    printf("\nError of initialisation renderer : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(-1);
}

printf("\n%d\n", errno);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the functions haven't reported an error, you should not check `errno`.  A function can set `errno` (usually as a side-effect), even though it succeeds.

It used to be the case (and probably still *is* the case, but I haven't checked for several years), the many of the Standard I/O functions on Solaris would set `errno` to `ENOTTY` when the output was not to a terminal, even though the function succeeded.  This is wholly legitimate.

See the C standard [§7.4 Errors `<errno.h>` §3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3) where it says:

> The value of `errno` in the initial thread is zero at program startup (the initial value of `errno` in other threads is an indeterminate value), but is never set to zero by any library function.<sup>202)</sup> The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard.
>
> <sup>202)</sup> Thus, a program that uses `errno` for error checking should set it to zero before a library function call, then inspect it before a subsequent library function call. Of course, a library function can save the value of `errno` on entry and then set it to zero, as long as the original value is restored if `errno`'s value is still zero just before the return.

---

TL;DR — don't check `errno` unless a function reports failure and is documented to set `errno` to a meaningful value on failure.